Create multiple dataframes from row values of a given dataframe
I have a dataframe storing information of 4 subjects A, B, C, D.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subject': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'X1': [80, 90, 70, 60],
    'Y1': [10, 25, 20, 15],
    'X2': [63, 75, 84, 92],
    'Y2': [13, 28, 25, 18],
    'X3': [36, 78, 64, 82],
    'Y3': [18, 25, 24, 16]
})
print(df)

From the above data frame, I want to create 4 data frames df_A, df_B, df_C and df_D such that the new data frame has x1, y1 as the first row, x2, y2 as second and x3, y3 as third.
Expects output data frames are
df_A = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [80, 63, 36],
    'Y': [10, 13, 18]
})
print(df_A)

df_B = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [90, 75, 78],
    'Y': [25, 28, 25]
})
print(df_B)

df_C = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [70, 84, 64],
    'Y': [20, 25, 24]
})
print(df_C)

df_D = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [60, 92, 82],
    'Y': [15, 18, 16]
})
print(df_D)

How do I achieve this? I tried with iloc but failed.

you can use wide_to_long() with groupby() like this:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subject': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'X1': [80, 90, 70, 60],
    'Y1': [10, 25, 20, 15],
    'X2': [63, 75, 84, 92],
    'Y2': [13, 28, 25, 18],
    'X3': [36, 78, 64, 82],
    'Y3': [18, 25, 24, 16]
})

df_long = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['X', 'Y'], i='subject', j='num', sep='').reset_index()

 subject  num   X   Y
0        A    1  80  10
1        B    1  90  25
2        C    1  70  20
3        D    1  60  15
4        A    2  63  13
5        B    2  75  28
6        C    2  84  25
7        D    2  92  18
8        A    3  36  18
9        B    3  78  25
10       C    3  64  24
11       D    3  82  16

df_list = [group.drop(columns=['subject', 'num']).reset_index(drop=True) for _, group in df_long.groupby('subject')]

for df in df_list:
    print(df)

   X   Y
0  80  10
1  63  13
2  36  18
    X   Y
0  90  25
1  75  28
2  78  25
    X   Y
0  70  20
1  84  25
2  64  24
    X   Y
0  60  15
1  92  18
2  82  16


A possible solution, which iterates over dataframe rows and gets all X values and Y values, respectively, from each row:
[pd.DataFrame({
    'X': y.iloc[1::2].to_list(), 
    'Y': y.iloc[2::2].to_list()}) 
 for _, y in df.iterrows()]


Alternatively, using np.reshape to conveniently reshape the values of the dataframe, and then vertically splitting the resulting array (with np.vsplit), to get the 4 dataframes:
n = 4
a = df.drop('subject', axis=1).values.reshape(-1, 2)
[pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['X', 'Y']) for x in np.vsplit(a, n)]


Output:
[    X   Y
 0  80  10
 1  63  13
 2  36  18,
     X   Y
 0  90  25
 1  75  28
 2  78  25,
     X   Y
 0  70  20
 1  84  25
 2  64  24,
     X   Y
 0  60  15
 1  92  18
 2  82  16]

